# Local ring of a smooth subvariety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ be an irreducible variety. Say $Y$ is a closed irreducible sub variety. Then is it true that $Y$ is smooth iff the local ring of $Y$ i.e. $\mathcal O_{X,Y}$ is regular ?

Comment: Certainly one direction is true. If $Y$ is smooth, then every localization at a maximal ideal is regular, and hence $\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}$ is regular as it is a localization of each of the local rings at points. The other direction is not as obvious, but maybe it is just too early here for me to think of it.

Comment: If $X= \mathrm{Spec}A$ is affine and smooth, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}$ is just a localization of $A$, hence regular. But certainly there are smooth affine schemes with singular closed subschemes. (Take e.g.\ $X= \mathbb{A}^2$ and $Y$ a nodal curve.) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Louis is correct.